# If VideoView Equal Null (if do not Exist video path)

Tags: android, android-videoview

I'm using a VideoView in an Android project and need to know if it is empty (null) or not.

How can I recognize whether a VideoView is empty or not?

I tried both of the following methods but neither worked.

```
if (videoView.equals(null)){

}else{

}
```

Or

```
if (videoView == null){

}else{

}
```

Comment: are you just trying to check if the video file exists at a given path or not?

Comment: Except this method is not any other way?

Comment: In that case, you can normally do a file-check

Answer (score 1):

As evident from your problem, you want to find out if the Video file exists or not at a given path. You can simply check it as you'd check for the existence of any other file:

```
File file = getContext().getFileStreamPath(FILE_NAME);

if(file.exists()){
    //play the video here
} else {
    //maybe show a toast message that the video file doesn't exist
}
```